# creating eclipse Project, "C/C++ Make Project" missing

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions on the following page,  http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs . I am having problem with Step 4, there isn't any option **"C/C++ Make Project"** in project properties, have repeated the steps again and again but couldn't identify the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31210/creating-eclipse-project,-%22c/c++-make-project%22-missing/) by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-04**:
Did you make sure to install the version of Eclipse for C/C++ development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe, there are packages which only builds a library, no executables. If you are is on eclipse, after doing make eclipse-project, import it as a " existing project into workspace". You can find this option under 'General'. This always works for me.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem, there should be a cpp file with main function , and its "rosbuild_add_executable" in CMakeLists, in order to successfully import the project. Blank project cannot be imported.

---

Originally posted by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) with karma: 46 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1